# How can I export the components declarated in entryComponents for other modules?

Tags: angular, dynamic-programming, angular-components

I'd like to create a component dynamically  in app.module, but the component is declarated in entryComponents in app.module

```
// page.module.ts
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
           ...
        DynamicComponent
    ],
    **entryComponents**: [
        **DynamicComponent**
    ],
    exports: [
        DynamicComponent,
          ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
    ]
})
```

How would be my app.module.ts to use the same entryComponent?

Answer (score 0):

I will only answer the question and warn you abotu declaring components in several modules. Now, for the answer : use the spread operator (`...`) and export an array as a variable.

```
export const entryComponents = [DynamicComponent];

@NgModule({
  declarations [
   ...entryComponents 
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...entryComponents
  ],
  exports: [
    ...entryComponents
  ]
})
```